# Using QGIS for current SAR (Search And Rescue) operation?

Tags: satellite, search

A friend of mine, Christiaan Wilson is missing since 15 may during descending the Dhaulagiri mountain in the Himalayas. One searching team has already finished one operation. A second is on the way.

More information about the search: https://www.christiaanwilson.nl/english/

But now we are looking for other options instead of helicopters and ground teams. From my Hydrology background I know that there are a lot of possibilities with satellites. For that I have already contact with a teacher of mine, but with more people involved the process can be faster. Do you know someone who can help me further with this? Or can you help me further? It would really help me and the people who are working day and night to find Christiaan.

It would be really nice, because every minute is vital.

Comment: Have you considered posting a Community Ad as per http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3947/115

Comment: FYI for Esri users, ESRI have a free tool for ArcGIS http://www.esri.com/apps/MapSAR/software/index.cfm